# Angular 2 + ngrx: Implement session timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am building an app with a session countdown, which gets set to 3600 after login.

When the timer reaches 60, the app should alert the user to extend the session. When the timer reaches 0, the app should logout.

Some requests (POST) reset the session timer, others do not.

I have an `auth.reducer` which handles cases like login, login_success etc. and an `auth.effect` class, where I set session-duration to the actual duration returned from the server.

My questions are:

1. where do I put and start the `Observable.timer/interval`?
   I have the following options:

   - `dashboard.component`
   - `auth.effects`
   - `auth.service`
2. Do I create an action `DECREMENT_TIMER` or do I just create an action `TIMER_TIMEOUT` when the Observable finishes the countdown?
3. How should I format the AuthState? Do I have a `sessionSecondsLeft` counter which gets decremented every second by `DECREMENT_TIMER` or is it better to just have a property `countdown_at_60` and `countdown_finished`?

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DECREMENT_TIMER` action would update your state once per second and would also spam your action log (if you're using store-devtools)

My suggestion:

Create an action `TIMER_RESET`. You can save a timestamp in the store, if you want to display it, but I don't think you need it until there's less than one minute left.

```
@Effect() TIMER_RESET$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(TIMER_RESET)
  .switchMap(
    Observable.concat(
      Observable.timer(1000*60*59).map({type: TIMER_WARNING}),
      Observable.timer(1000*60*1).map({type: TIMER_EXPIRED})
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand would have to implement another timer that would countdown from 3600 - 60 to call the TIMER_RESET action. I have one question though. Where would I put that timer? auth.service or dashboard.component?

Comment: Well, no. After `TIMER_RESET` fired, the first Observable will dispatch `TIMER_WARNING` after 59 minutes and the second one will dispatch `TIMER_EXPIRED` 1 minute after that. `Observable.concat()` subscribes to the passed Observables _in sequence_. If another `TIMER_RESET` is dispatched before, both timers will be discarded for new ones.

Comment: Ok I see now, I call timer_reset after login_success or after every POST request. Thanks.

Comment: Still unclear who kicks off the first timer. I would guess it is your `dashboard.component.ngOnInit()`